# Will deleting DAG data remove the blockchain data too?

Tags: private-blockchain, nodes, dag

As we know DAG data is stored in:

```
 Mac/Linux: $(HOME)/.ethash/
```

My blockchain has been running for  2 months, so there is more than one file in the above directory.

**Question** 1: Can I remove the older versions?

**Question** 2: If I mistakenly remove the current version, would my blockchain data (e.g. transactions and deployed contract) be deleted?

Answer (score 1):

> Question 1: Can I remove the older versions?

You should keep the *two* most recent files. It's possible/likely that the most recent file is the future, pre-generated DAG that will be used in the next epoch.

> Question 2: If I mistakenly remove the current version, would my
>   blockchain data (e.g. transactions and deployed contract) be deleted?

No - the DAG file is a separate entity used in mining. It just means you'll have to wait for the current DAG file to be regenerated next time you start your client.